# How to write validation rule for JSON laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

There is JSON object that I want to validate:

```
[{
  "id": 1,
  "settings": {
    "GRSYSEM": 1
  }
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "settings": {
    "GRSYSEM": 1
  }
},
{
  "id": 3,
  "settings": {
    "GRSYSEM": 1
  }
}
]
```

How to write validation rule in Laravel?

I tried this rule:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'id' => 'required|array',
    'id.*' => 'required',
    'settings.*.GRSYSEM' => 'required'
]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there, simply put the wildcard `*` first:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    '*.id' => 'required',
    '*.settings.GRSYSEM' => 'required'
]);
```

It literally says: For each element in the array, I expect an `id` and a setting `GRSYSEM`.

You could also ensure it's an array by using a little hack:

```
$data = ['input' => $request->all()];

$validator = Validator::make($data, [
    'input' => 'required|array',
    'input.*.id' => 'required',
    'input.*.settings.GRSYSEM' => 'required'
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If entry in `$request->all()` is id (as I can see), you should try like that :

```php
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'id' => 'required|array',
    'id.*.id' => 'required',
    'id.*.settings.GRSYSEM' => 'required'
]);
```