# How to validate array in Laravel with Request?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8, request-validation

I send to `Laravel` this `JSON` data:

```
[
  {"name":"...", "description": "..."},
  {"name":"...", "description": "..."}
]
```

I have a StoreRequest class extends `FormRequest`:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class StoreRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|string|min:1|max:255',
            'description' => 'nullable|string|max:65535'
        ];
    }
}
```

In my controller I have this code, but it doesn't work with array:

```php
    public function import(StoreRequest $request) {
        $item = MyModel::create($request);

        return Response::HTTP_OK;
    }
```

I found this solution to handle arrays in the Request rules():

```php
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|string|min:1|max:255',
            'name.*' => 'required|string|min:1|max:255',
            'description' => 'nullable|string|max:65535'
            'description.*' => 'nullable|string|max:65535'
        ];
    }
```

How can I update the `StoreRequest` and/or the `import()` code to avoide duplicate lines in `rules()`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write validation rule for JSON laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57545675/how-to-write-validation-rule-for-json-laravel)

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry. I overlooked the `[]` and was confused. Please have a look at the linked question and my answer there.

Comment: @Namoshek: I think this isn't a duplicate... In this linked site they use `$validator = Validator::make()` what I don't use, because I have a StoreRequest class. Or if this is a same thing, then I dont understand how can I use this two together.

Comment: The rules returned by the `rules()` method are used to create a `Validator` as discussed in the other question. It is the same thing, just an abstraction of it...

Comment: Basically, form request classes (like your `StoreRequest`) are used to extract logic from the controller. You can do exactly the same stuff also with a normal `Request` object and the `Validator` in your controller. It is still recommended to use form requests in order to keep your controller small and simple.

Comment: Isn't there a way to explode my JSON array to data instances and validate one-by-one with a `foreach()` use with the basic `StoreRequest` ? I don't want to rewrite the `StoreRequest` in the controller (like in the linked question)... Mostly because of I have 50+ fields to validate.

Comment: I don't get the question. Why don't you just put the validation rules for the request parameters in the `rules()` function? What you currently have in above written question is almost fine, just remove the rules without asterisk (`*`) and move the asterisk of the remaining rules to the front.

Comment: @Namoshek so I have 55 fileds in a JSON object what I need to validate. Of course I can duplicate each lines in the `rules()` but in this case it will be longer, uglier and less maintainable in my opinion. This last is the main reason why I asked this question. I have a validation ruleset to one instance. I think there is a built in way to validate an array of instances with this single ruleset.

Comment: ...without modify the ruleset.

Comment: That's exactly what my linked answer tries to explain. For an array of objects, you simply use `*` as indicator for the array.

Comment: @Namoshek : I understand that, but the question is: will this `*.` solution working with a non-array objects too?

Answer (score 1):

As you have an array of data you need to put `*` first:

```php
public function rules()
{
   return [
       '*.name' => 'required|string|min:1|max:255',
       '*.description' => 'nullable|string|max:65535',
   ];
}
```

Comment: Will this working with a single (non array) objects too?

Comment: No, this would require the rules without `*.`. You can't do both in one ruleset without duplication. IMHO the best way would be to always send an array or use two different FormRequests as they are doing two different things (creating one record vs. creating many records).